# Base stats for all vocations at level 99 in Dragon Quest IX?

Tags: dragon-quest-9

I'm currently trying to decide on what will be the "main" jobs for my characters in DQ9. Does anyone have a chart showing what every job's base stats (before bonuses from skill points and seeds) would be at level 99? Since abilities are shared between jobs, picking a main job is mostly just about the final stats and equipment, at least for non-spellcasters.

Comment: Is this with/with-out the boosts gained from a signature skill?
*Paladin-Virtue etc.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes!

```
                 Str  Agl  Res  Dft  Chm  MMend MMght  MxHP  MxMP
Warrior:         404   78  400  111   89      0     0   570    86
Priest:          201  312  204  206  146    400     0   420   315
Mage:             96  401  162  304  155      0   400   390   364
Martial Artist:  399  500  245  255  120      0     0   540    38
Thief:           299  410  241  402   58     81     0   510   132
Minstrel:        246  359  237  304  245    195   161   480   179
Gladiator:       500  124  322  256   90      0     0   540    41
Paladin:         354   73  360    9  116    164     0   600   175
Armamentalist    351  173  243  110  185      0   282   540   226
Ranger:          305  264  241  500   61    200     0   510   229
Sage:            202  218  202   57  235    208   237   480   500
Luminary:        148  360  205  259  300    318    77   510   220
```

(http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/937281-dragon-quest-ix-sentinels-of-the-starry-skies/56310289)

Comment: Ah, thanks. I looked through all of the actual FAQs I think, but didn't look on the forums. One comment a little ways down the thread says that the Warrior MP should be 86 instead of 87 though.

Comment: Thanks for the correction!  I looked for typos as I transcribed the chart, but I didn't see the comments in the thread.  :)

Comment: My Minstrel stats are higher than the ones on chart .-.: Strength:346
Agility:559
Resilience:437
Deftness:514
Charm:345
Magical Mending:495
Magical Might:461
Max HP:780
Max MP:299 Is it because I've maxed all skills for every class? .-.

Comment: @Popcycle33 - The above table is only for *base* stats - no seeds, no other bonuses. You've probably upgraded your Minstrel.